# Is it legal to buy software license keys from "bulk" sites?

Tags: licensing, software

http://www.windows7keyonsale.com/about.html

Seems legit. They buy license at bulk and sell it.

Comment: Honestly, just a few minutes googling will reveal lots of reasons to think that neither it, nor its sister site with the same ownership `buykeyonline.com`, are legitimate.

Comment: such as? they are much cheaper. perhaps microsoft sell those

Comment: Just punch the site name into google. Also, punch in "buykeyonline.com", which has the same look and feel and the same owner. The most common scam is selling keys that are tied to an account they cancel a month or two later.

Comment: Some cheap key sellers engage in dubious behaviour to obtain the keys. Some sell the same key to multiple buyers, some use credit card fraud. Even splitting volume licenses or reselling OEM keys without the associated hardware might not be allowed in all jurisdictions (MS certainly doesn't want you to do so).

Comment: I suspect those are keys from MSDN subscriptions, probably educational ones. Some schools don't care how valuable is stuff they get for free, and hand them out automatically with every application. You can register hundreds of fake students and you get several keys for every account. That's assuming the keys are not plain made up.

Comment: @Agent_L And then it's not uncommon for the keys to be revoked a few months later. I've seen fake packaging and fake certificates of authenticity too. *Stay away from sites like these.*

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, well, if a key will last 6 months, than 3 years worth of shady keys is still cheaper than a legit license : ) After 3 years you change computers anyway, so real Windows license could be treated as worthless after 3 years. This might change if indeed W10 is intended to move to OSX-like model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many aspect to this.

First of all, there is a license which is a deal between a manufacturer of the software and the entity who bought those keys (assuming that key dealer bought them lawfully). This license often directly forbids further sale of such keys. So according to manufacturer they can be "pirated".

Secondly, there is a law applicable to your jurisdiction. Eg in EU resale of used software is always legal and cannot be taken away by the license. So according to the law they may be legal.

Another issue here is what proof of purchase you'll get from the key dealer? Your local jurisdiction may not recognize this transaction at all without a proper receipt or invoice.

This only skims the surface, because later you might want to exercise rights from the license (eg right to tech support or updates), however the license might be already violated. So you might end up in situation in which the software is legal to poses but not fully-functional (or perhaps not functional at all).

Finally, there is the question of good faith. Were you acting in good faith buying those keys? If you have the knowledge that keys are stolen, then you're committing a different crime here, sometimes even "worse" than pirating.

Comment: Just because something is cheaper doesn't mean that it's illegal. But besides the fact that it's cheaper I see no other reason why it's not right. I just wonder how do they got those keys. Some would actually have many unsold cd whose license key they take

Comment: @JimThio I never said "illegal because cheap". And I believe I've explained pretty well why it may or may not be right. If you have any questions to my answer I'll be happy to address them.

Comment: Let's get practical, what sort of problem I will get if I buy from them? I mean anyone can just use dazloader and get legit windows 10.

Comment: @JimThio How can I know? You didn't even wrote what country are you in. Maybe they cut off right hand for license breach in your jurisdiction? In mine every soft is considered illegal unless you can prove how you obtained it. This site looks shady as hell - stay clear. Buy keys from ebay or amazon or allegro or some other big and reputable site that will give you proof of purchase and will fight for you if the seller sends non-functioning keys. Be prepared that the system can go from "genuine" to "pirated" without warning whenever MS figures out that this key was resold.

Comment: I am in indonesia. Pirate heaven he he he he. However, I want to stay legit. I mean the programmer at microsoft deserve something.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing legit about this site - if you go to [this](http://www.windows7keyonsale.com/about.html) link on it they claim they "sell only new OEM software".  This is a breach of the Microsoft EULAs.

Further, look at the section titled "How are you able to sell your software at such low prices" in the [FAQ](http://www.windows7keyonsale.com/faq.html)  and you will see they have no agreement with the manufacturers - which means they can't be negotiating a different EULA.

That the products don't come with a COA should also raise alarm bells - although this is not, by itself sufficient to say they are not leget.

Further, there is no meaningful contact details provided, and the way the site is set up is on the cheap (Godaddy as the register for a start), with hidden domain registration.  Also, merchants of a large enough scale to get prices down as low as these guys claim would not be using (only) Paypal to accept payment.  FOLLOW THE MONEY !